# How can I use PowerBI to generate growth rates?

Tags: powerbi, dax

How can I use PowerBI to get the growth rate for each specific category (id)?
I have prepared a sample, but the only data resource is daily data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1612EDt2CqzF4PT8U6HGiVXCI7kFWXH7JPQjJuxfnVPE/edit#gid=0

In addition, the data you want to get the growth rate from is data that is accumulated daily, such as the number of followers.

If possible, I'd like to show the growth rate as a percentage of the previous day, the previous week, or the previous month.

I have prepared a calendar table.

I'm new to PowerBI, but I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: Can you share what you have tried, your sample date and the desired output in tabular form?

Comment: Sorry about that.
I forgot to include a sample spreadsheet.

I've edited it now, please check it.